# How does one seperate parts of an image using EaselJS canvas manipulation library

Tags: easeljs

I'm trying to create segmented parts of an image... like the top right square of an image can be highlighted or clicked on while the rest of the image isn't. I tried to google this stuff and I found codes related to container but I'm not sure if that's what I want.. How can I make parts of image segmented so I can fire events on mouseover/mouseselect etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could either define a `hitArea` (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_hitArea) if your image only requires one segment or if you want multiple clickeable areas on one image: Split up the image through using multiple `Shapes` via `beginnBitmapFill` (an example for bitmapFill can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/nmLhu/) and then put the listeners on the individual shapes.